# How to make an element droppable after page has been loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

The basic scenario is that I have a grid of days/times that are to contain reservations for each of them.  The user drags items to be reserved from a list to each of the droppable slots, and this works fine.

At initialization, the grid is loaded with existing reservations and are placed into the slot(s) by my PHP script.  At *that point*, a reserved slot should not, and is NOT droppable (because it's already been reserved).  This is visually apparent by using `activeclass` in the `droppabe` function - the reserved cells are not highlighted with the activeclass, and cannot receive the draggable.

**Droppables at initialization:**

```
<div id="slot-1" class="slot reserved">
    <div id="item-1" class="item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle">RsvnName</div>
</div>

<div id="slot-2" class="slot available ui-droppable" ></div>
```

I then use `accept: checkReservation` to insure that slots are empty before allowing the drop, and if the drop is allowed, "swap" the available/reserved classes with `removeClass` and `addClass` of the two droppables so that the now-unreserved slot can be dropped into and reserved with a different item.  I should mention that returning an unconditional true in checkReservation has no effect on the problem.

**Relevant JS**

```
$(".available").droppable({
    accept: acceptReservations,
    activeClass: "candrop",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.draggable).parent().addClass('available');
            $(ui.draggable).parent().removeClass('reserved');
```

.
.
.

```
function acceptReservations(ele) {
    // Slot may only contain 1 Item
    canReserve = ($(this).find(".item").length > 0) ? false : true;
    return canReserve;
}
```

**Droppables AFTER moving Item from one slot to another**

```
<div id="slot-1" class="slot available"></div>
<div id="slot-2" class="slot reserved" >
    <div id="item-1" class="item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" >RsvnName</div>
</div>
```

Apparently addClass/removeClass is not sufficient to tell jQuery that the slot is now droppable.  The HTML after the drop is visually correct, but jQuery is unaware that the empty slot should now be droppable.  I *did* try `.addClass('ui-droppable')`, but that had no affect, so it seems clear to me that I'm missing a vital step to make the now-empty slot droppable.

So, it seems the real question is how to make an element droppable that was not droppable when the page was initially loaded.

Comment: Please create a fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to [destroy](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-destroy) or [disable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-disable) (*whichever is preferable for you*) the current [droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) before switching classes

```
$(".available").droppable("destroy"); // destroy the existing droppable - which is now reserved.
```

and and re-initialize the new sortable afterwards.

```
$(".available").droppable({ // now initialize the newly available droppable.
 accept: acceptReservations,
 activeClass: "candrop",
 drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).parent().addClass('available');
      $(ui.draggable).parent().removeClass('reserved');
      ...
```

*Side note: in description you mentioned you're using `accept: checkReservation`, but in actual code you're using `accept: acceptReservations`*

Comment: Thanks!- I was afraid that might be the answer...I was hoping there was a simpler way. also, the discrepancy in fcn name was a cut/paste/typo error while pruning the code for the question.